# Substituir duplo for por duplo lapply

Tags: r

Pessoal estou tentando substituir meu código que possui duplo for por um com duplo lapply com objetivo de otimizar o programa já que o r trabalha de forma matricial, esta funcional desta forma:

```
k<-1
for(i in 1:nrow(tab1)){
   for(j in 1:nrow(tab2)){


      tab3$col1[k]<-tab1$col1[i]
      tab3$col2[k]<-tab2$col3[j]
      k<-k+1

    }

  }
```

Gostaria que ficasse assim, mas não sei como fazer podem ajudar?Obrigado

```
lapply(1:nrow(tab1),fuction(i){
  lapply(1:nrow(tab2), function(j){

   ??????????

  })
})
```

Comment: Teoricamente, trocar pelo lapply não vai fazer diferença nenhuma. O R só é mais rápido se vc usar funções vetorizadas, escritas em C/C++ caso contrário o for e os outros são equivalentes.

Comment: Porque não `tab3$col1 <- tab1$col1` e `tab3$col2 <- tab2$col3`? Note que como o seu código está, a instrução `k <- k + 1` vai executar `nrow(tab1)*nrow(tab2)` vezes. É isso que quer?

Comment: O código possui várias estruturas condicionais que quando satisfeitas gravam registros diferentes em cada linha, mas como o amigo disse que a troca do for pelo lapply não faz diferença vou procurar outra solução porque do jeito que está demora muito a ler as tabelas acho que vou partir para uma solução em PYTHON. Obrigado

Comment: Acho em python não vai ficar muito mais rápido também. Assim como no R, loops são ineficientes no python. A melhor solução seria fazer em C ou C++... Da uma olhada no pacote RCpp.

Comment: Puts no phyton também! Valeu Daniel vou partir pro C então

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

Na verdade os apply's podem ser até mais lentos que loops, se no loop você tomar o cuidado de pré-alocar seu vetor.

Quanto ao seu problema, parece que você quer fazer todas as combinações de
tab1$col1 e tab2$col3.

Sugiro usar `expand.grid()`:

```
tab3 <- expand.grid(col1 = tab1$col1, col2 = tab2$col3)
```

A ordem será diferente, mas isso se resolve fácil com `order()`.

Um abraço!